# Postgres pg_toast in autovacuum - which table?

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

I have an autovacuum process running on pg_toast:

```
select query, from pg_stat_activity where query like '%autov%';
"autovacuum: VACUUM pg_toast.pg_toast_15404513 "
```

How do I find out what table/index/whatever this pg_toast pertains to? Or is the autovacuum working on something else?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you'll want something like:

```
select n.nspname, c.relname 
from pg_class c 
inner join pg_namespace n on c.relnamespace = n.oid
where reltoastrelid = (
    select oid
    from pg_class 
    where relname = 'pg_toast_15404513' 
    and relnamespace = (SELECT n2.oid FROM pg_namespace n2 WHERE n2.nspname = 'pg_toast') )
```

It'd be nice if Pg reported this in the vacuum command summary.

Comment: Is there a way to list real name of all pg_toast_xxx ? thanks.

Comment: @wolf97084, here is query for listing all pg_toast_xxx and their real name `select r.relname, t.relname from pg_class r inner join pg_class t on t.reltoastrelid = r.oid;`

Answer (score 41):

Here's a shorter way:

```
select 15404513::regclass;
```

where `15404513` is `pg_toast_` suffix.

Comment: This would return the correct name of the table only if run in the correct DB.